# How to to generate email with attachments, using Outlook and Excel, and preserve formatting?

Tags: excel, vba, outlook, email-attachments

I have an Excel document called "Test.xlsx":
[image]

I have the following VBA code:

```
Sub Send_multiple_Email()
Dim sh As Worksheet
Dim sPath As String
Dim sName As String
Dim OA As Object
Dim msg As Object
Dim i As Integer
Dim last_row As Integer

Set sh = ThisWorkbook.Sheets("Ark1")
Set OA = CreateObject("Outlook.Application")
last_row = Application.WorksheetFunction.CountA(sh.Range("A:A"))

For i = 2 To last_row
Set msg = OA.createitem(0)

msg.to = sh.Range("A" & i).Value
msg.cc = sh.Range("B" & i).Value
msg.Subject = sh.Range("C" & i).Value
msg.body = sh.Range("D" & i).Value

If sh.Range("E" & i).Value <> "" Then
msg.attachments.Add sh.Range("E" & i).Value
End If

sPath = Environ("UserProfile")

'msg.display
'msg.send
msg.SaveAs "C:\Users\xx\Desktop\Save_emails_in_this_folder\" & msg.Subject & ".msg", 3

Next i

End Sub
```

(I run the VBA from the Excel spreadsheet.)

I save the emails instead of sending them, so I can check they are correct.

It saves the emails in the correct location, with customized mail text and customized attachments, however, the formatting is not retained. (The fat text is not fat, and the logo, which is an image disappears as well.)

A solution to this would be to write the "Body-text" in Word or Outlook, but I can't get it to work.

Comment: Is there a reason for not using built-in mail merge functionality?

Comment: Yes, the standard built-in function is not able to add attachments. Also, I want different attachment for each mail and I want to save the mails at the computer, such that I can check them before sending them manually. If they look fine I can run the VBA again and send them directly. VBA is more flexible and can be adjusted and modified for the specific purpose.

Answer (score 2):

You are setting up a plain text property:

```
msg.body = sh.Range("D" & i).Value
```

To preserve any formatting and embed images you need to use the `HTMLBody` property or deal with the Word object model to paste everything from Excel directly. The [WordEditor](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/office/vba/api/outlook.inspector.wordeditor) property returns the Microsoft Word Document Object Model of the message being displayed. So, basically, you could utilize the copy/paste operation.

---

The Outlook object model supports three main ways of customizing the message body:

1. The [Body](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/vba/outlook-vba/articles/mailitem-body-property-outlook) property returns or sets a string representing the clear-text body of the Outlook item.
2. The [HTMLBody](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/vba/outlook-vba/articles/mailitem-htmlbody-property-outlook) property of the MailItem class returns or sets a string representing the HTML body of the specified item. Setting the `HTMLBody` property will always update the Body property immediately. For example:

```
     Sub CreateHTMLMail() 
       'Creates a new e-mail item and modifies its properties. 
       Dim objMail As Outlook.MailItem 
       'Create e-mail item 
       Set objMail = Application.CreateItem(olMailItem) 
       With objMail 
        'Set body format to HTML 
        .BodyFormat = olFormatHTML 
        .HTMLBody = "<HTML><BODY>Enter the message <a href="http://google.com">text</a> here. </BODY></HTML>" 
        .Display 
       End With 
     End Sub
```

3. The Word object model can be used for dealing with message bodies. See [Chapter 17: Working with Item Bodies](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd492012(v=office.12).aspx) for more information.

Note, the [MailItem.BodyFormat](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/vba/outlook-vba/articles/mailitem-bodyformat-property-outlook) property allows you to programmatically change the editor that is used for the body of an item.

Comment: You're using late binding so you either need to declare a constant `Const olFormatHTML = 2` or just swap it out for `2`

Comment: Nothing seems to work. I also tried the approach, based on an .oft template, that doesn't work either.

Comment: What code did you try to use? I still see the `Body` property in your code.